# JVM Heap Size Docker

Tags: java, docker, jvm, heap-memory

I'm strugling trying to set the Heap size insise a docker container, I'm aware of similar questions but non of them seams to work for me, I'm sure I'm missing something.

My docker file look like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=target/spring-boot-web.jar

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-XX:+UseContainerSupport" , "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0", "-XshowSettings" ,"-jar","app.jar"]
```

When I build and execute the image above with the following command:
`docker run -m 2G -p 8080:8080 -t springtest`

I get te following information due to `-XshowSettings`:

> VM settings: Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 910.50M

After a few seconds my app start without a problem and then I decide to fetch information about the JVM inside the container with the command `docker exec MyContainerId java -XshowSettings` and I it prints :

> VM settings: Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 455.50M

It's clear that the container start with 50% of Max Ram but after the app starts it reduces to the default (25%)

Maybe I have a wrong understanding of JVM and containers,  can some one point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: You're running two jvms. One with `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50.0` and one with the default settings.

Comment: How am I running two JVM? Because when I run the exec command on the container?

Comment: Yes, exec runs a command in the container. You are running the command `java` which starts a new JVM.